# Не могу получить удалённую ветку из github

Tags: git, github, git-checkout

[image: Сама ветка есть]

На удалённом репозитории сама ветка есть

```
git fetch
```

со всеми его вариациями работает.

Но ветка так и не появляется(((

```
git checkout SUN-36--useauto-direct-conversion
error: pathspec 'SUN-36--useauto-direct-conversion' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: ``git branch --list`` что говорит?

Answer (score 0):

1. Удалённая ветка `SUN-36--useauto-direct-conversion` в вашей копии будет иметь имя `remotes/origin/SUN-36--useauto-direct-conversion` (вместо `origin` может быть другое имя удалённого репозитория, если вы это указали). Уточнить имя вы можете командой `git branch --list --all`
2. На удалённую ветку нельзя переключиться. Их можно менять только командами `push` и `fetch`/`pull`. Вам необходимо сначала создать локальную ветку, ассоциированную с `remotes/origin/SUN-36--useauto-direct-conversion` командой `git branch -t SUN-36--useauto-direct-conversion remotes/origin/SUN-36--useauto-direct-conversion`, и после этого можно на неё переключаться.

Когда внесёте изменения в локальную ветку, вы сможете отправить их в удалённый репозиторий, в соответствующую ветку, командой `git push`